# Il n'a pas dit quand il

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, discours-indirect

Something bothers me about the following sentence:

> Il n'a pas dit quand il **vient** nous rendre visite.

I keep wondering why 'vient'.

I would say:

> Il n'a pas dit quand il **viendrait** nous rendre visite.

Because of the indirect speech and sequence of tenses. Is that wrong and if it is, why?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

J'utiliserai même plus volontiers le futur (la visite a toutes les chances d'être réalisée) :

> Il n'a pas dit quand il **viendra** nous rendre visite.

Certainement pas le présent puisque c'est une action qui n'est pas simultanée au fait de le dire.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: It could be the present when it's a regular action (i.e. which day, which time a weekly or daily visit happens), but there's just not enough context to tell.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My first post was pretty doubtful. Soz.

There is two "conditionnel" types :

- *Le conditionnel temporel*, which is used to speak about a "future" event in a past-viewpoint.

> Hier, il a dit qu'il parlerait couramment le français d'ici 2 ans.
>
> Yesterday, he said he would be fluent in french in 2 years. (Translation could be inexact)

- *Le conditionnel modal,* which is used to speak about imaginary, possibility, opinion and uncertain things.

So you should use

> quand il **viendrait**

As it is a future in a past-viewpoint.

I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess I should check the use of ''quand'' with tenses.

Comment: You're welcome, but don't worry too much. Usually a lot of french don't even pay attention to these kind on things, even me. I usually say "Quand il viendrait" even if it's a bit wrong !

Comment: Oh, that's nice but...
One more thing, if you don't mind.
The sentence is ''discours indirect'' ( Il a dit que/quand... etc ) and let's say 'he' used future.
Je viendrai vous rendre visite.
Il a dit qu'il viendrait nous rendre visite.
Now this is ok ( I suppose ) but this is not the same thing as my earlier example because of ''quand''?

Comment: IMO when you use "quand" instead of "que", you're not really using "discours indirect". I mean, I never heard "Il m'a dit quand il viendrait". We would use "Il m'a dit à quelle heure / quelle date / il viendrait". And in this case, you use the conditional to translate a "Spoken future in past".. I should edit my post.

Comment: Je ne le comprends pas. Par exemple: Quand a-t-il du temps? - Je ne sais pas quand il a du temps. C'est l'interrogation indirecte. Exemple: Il m'a demandé: « Quand tu seras dispo? » -> Il m'a demandé quand je serais dispos. J'ai utilisé la concordance des temps: future -> conditonnel. Je pense que mon exemple « Il n'a pas dit quand il... » est la même chose. Mais peut-être j'ai tort parce qu'il n'y a pas de question alors je ne peux pas utiliser le même raisonnement.  By the way, thank you for your time. I'm really confused about this one.

Comment: And that's exactly the point ! What I said is basicly : If the _taleteller_ speak about a **PAST** discussion "il **a dit**" **AND** if the speaker (the "IL") was speaking about **FUTURE** `"Je serai disponible demain"`. So you **must** use "conditionnel". The "concordance des temps" is directly in link with this rule. And **yes** your sentence was correct `Il n'a pas dit quand il viendrait nous rendre visite.`